# Make REST Framework require authentication for GET method

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm working on an Django app that uses REST Framework together with Swagger. Also added some models, and one of them is called `Example`. Added some views based on mixins in `views.py` for the model previously mentioned.

In `views.py`, I've created two classes: `ExampleList` (that uses `GET` to get all the objects made out from that model and `POST` to add a new model) and `ExampleIndividual`, that uses methods such as individual `GET`, `PUT` and `DELETE`.

Anyways, this is how my `ExampleList` class looks like:

```
class ExampleList(mixins.ListModelMixin, mixins.CreateModelMixin, generics.GenericAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = ExampleModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ExampleSerializer

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

In the `settings.py` file, in the `REST_FRAMEWORK` configuration, I've set:

```
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
]
```

Everything works fine at this moment. What I want to do, is, whenever I want to get the list of all objects from the `Example` model (access the `get()` method from the `ExampleList()` class, I want it to work only if I am authenticated (using the `Authorize` option from Swagger). If not, a status code like "FORBIDDEN" should be returned.

I tried using `permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]` at the beginning of the method, but it didn't work. It seems that I can still `GET` all the objects without being authenticated into Swagger.

Any advice on how I can do that properly? Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you are looged out ? Check you browser cookies, remove `session_id` and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried it with Token Authentication? With this method in each request made to the API, the token must be included in the Header Field Authorization. https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication to test it in Browser you can install an extension called Mod Header https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modheader/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj there you can include the token in the header field.

Comment: I don't want to try it with tokens. I want to use authentication based on username and password (existing in the database)

Comment: Then you can check @login_required. Maybe this helps: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator
Or the django "raw way" https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users